# Why do I get a segfault since my application was compiled for 64 bits?

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel

I am running a application(compiled over a 64 bit machine) over a 64 bit Linux system(RHEL5.5). This application is getting crashed after every 40-50 minutes.I am surprised to see this as it was running completely fine when I was running the same code on a 32 bit machine.

One of the possible causes I found that free memory in problematic system was only 50 MB.So I assumed that it is crashing because of low memory.But I also saw that system have around 5 GB of cached memory.I assumed that this cache memory should be available for all of my memory requests.Am I correct in this assumption or I free this cache after a while to solve this problem.

In the system Log I saw following message when my application is crashing:
kernel: MyApplicationName[20655]: segfault at 0000000030363938 rip 0000000000b35c7e rsp 00000000f322a3a0 error 4

can anyone point what can be the problem here?What this error 4 means in the system.

Comment: What's the point of leaving your RAM idle? Might as well use it as cache until an application needs it...

Answer (score 1):

Error 4 is EINTR, it's in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` :

```
#define EINTR            4      /* Interrupted system call */
```

But your problem does not seem related to memory or to this error 4 at all. It's more probably a bug which appeared because the code of your application was not ready for 64 bits system. Your main problem is not `error 4`, it's the `segfault`.

A segmentation fault error is when an application tries to use memory it cannot or has not the rights to use. In this case, Kernel has often no other choice but to stop it.

In order to have more info about this error, you can compile your application with debug symbol, attach gdb to your process and ask a full trace when the segfault occurs with this command in gdb shell `thread apply all bt`.

Comment: could also run `strace myprogram` to see which system call is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

The cache will be freed when needed. Your issue is far more likely to be poor code practices, possibly your code assuming all ints are 32bit.